# Customizing InfowindowAdapter to add images from Content provider

Tags: android, database, sqlite, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have an application of places shown on a map with markers, I have customized infowindow to show the contents of the places created, title, description and picture, these data are accessed via a content provider, my problem everything is going great until I delete a record from the database, the app goes crazy, or broken or just odd recognizes records id etc etc 
The problem is clearly in the infowindow code customization, because to remove it all works correctly, create, delete, create markers etc. .. but even though I've tried have not given with the error.

The infernal code:

```
class MyInfoWindowAdapter implements InfoWindowAdapter {

    View v;

    MyInfoWindowAdapter() {
        v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_info, null);

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(final Marker marker) {

        MapaLugaresActivity.this.marker = marker;

        c.requery();

        TextView tvTitulo = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tituloi);
        tvTitulo.setText(marker.getTitle());
        // TextView tvDescr = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.descripcioni);
        // tvDescr.setText(marker.getSnippet());
        ImageView imgi = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgi);

        if (marker.getSnippet() != null && marker != null
                && c.getCount() > 0) {

            try {

                if (c.moveToFirst()) {

                    c.moveToPosition(Integer.valueOf(marker.getSnippet()) - 1);

                    String img = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("foto"));

                    if (img != null) {

                        resizedBitmap = DecodeImagen
                                .decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(img, 100, 100);
                        imgi.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                        imgi.setImageBitmap(resizedBitmap);

                    } else {

                        imgi.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                        imgi.setImageResource(R.drawable.paisaje);

                    }

                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        // imgi.setImageResource(R.drawable.rdlv);

        Typeface fuente = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                "TravelingTypewriter.ttf");

        tvTitulo.setTypeface(fuente);
        // tvDescr.setTypeface(fuente);

        return v;

    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
        if (MapaLugaresActivity.this.marker != null
                && MapaLugaresActivity.this.marker.isInfoWindowShown()) {
            MapaLugaresActivity.this.marker.hideInfoWindow();
            MapaLugaresActivity.this.marker.showInfoWindow();
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

Add markers:

```
                 @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void addMarker() {

    map.clear();
    c.requery();

    if (c.getCount() > 0) {

        c.moveToFirst();

        do {

            latlong = new LatLng(c.getFloat(c.getColumnIndex("latitud")),
                    c.getFloat(c.getColumnIndex("longitud")));
            final MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().title(c
                    .getString(c.getColumnIndex("titulo")));
            marker.snippet(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("_id")));

            marker.position(latlong);

            map.addMarker(marker).showInfoWindow();

        } while (c.moveToNext());

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(MapaLugaresActivity.this, "Añada un nuevo lugar",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

I appreciate your help in advance, took several days trying to find the solution and I think it was time to ask for help, thanks.  I have limited programming experience , hope your understanding

PS: I have uploaded the project on GitHub in case anyone wants to analyze it: D

The code in the activity MapaLugaresActivity

https://github.com/Shochlves/rdlv

Image infowindow:

https://lh5.ggpht.com/eBgrw0riQxfGph4FhxXvMRDxzYjlvdWw6L6qRqg_L1oV9yPGHPW9wV2Cal7zVGj1-HY=h900-rw

Comment: Are you reloading your `Cursor` after you delete rows in the database?

Comment: I do not, as it should do? NotifyChange ()? forgive my ignorance on this point and thanks for the prompt reply

Comment: I can't tell you what you *should* do in this case, as I do not know enough about your app. However, if you *do* update your `Cursor`, you would *also* need to rebuild all your markers, as you are storing a `Cursor`-specific position in the snippet.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm trying to requery () (deprecated) and map.clear (), it seems that some progress but not get it to work correctly, any help is appreciated, I'm stuck on this problem and I will not stop until achieving solution 
They have a link to Github if you want a better look ... thanks

Comment: I updated the current code in question and added the method to add the markers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! The solution has been implemented Hastable (http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Hashtable.html), I hit the code as it is helpful. 
InfoWindowAdapter with image and title from SQLite (content provider)

InfoWindowAdapter:

```
public class MyInfoWindowAdapter implements InfoWindowAdapter {



    private View v;

    MyInfoWindowAdapter() {
        v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_info, null);

    }
    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
        if (MapaLugaresActivity.this.marker != null
                && MapaLugaresActivity.this.marker.isInfoWindowShown()) {
            MapaLugaresActivity.this.marker.hideInfoWindow();
            MapaLugaresActivity.this.marker.showInfoWindow();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {

        MapaLugaresActivity.this.marker = marker;
        String img = null;

         if (marker.getId() != null && markers != null && markers.size() > 0) {
                if ( markers.get(marker.getId()) != null &&
                        markers.get(marker.getId()) != null) {
                    img = markers.get(marker.getId());
                }
            }
        final ImageView imgi = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgi);

        if (img != null && !img.equalsIgnoreCase("null")
                && !img.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {

            Bitmap resizedBitmap = DecodeImagen
                    .decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(img, 100, 100);

            imgi.setImageBitmap(resizedBitmap);

        } else {
            imgi.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
            imgi.setImageResource(R.drawable.paisaje);
        }


        TextView tvTitulo = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tituloi);
        tvTitulo.setText(marker.getTitle());
        //TextView tvDescr = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.descripcioni);
        //tvDescr.setText(marker.getSnippet());



        Typeface fuente = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                "TravelingTypewriter.ttf");

        tvTitulo.setTypeface(fuente);
        // tvDescr.setTypeface(fuente);


        return v;

    }



}
```

addMarker:

```
public void addMarker() {

    markers = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    c.requery();

    if (c.getCount() > 0) {

        c.moveToFirst();

        do {


            latlong = new LatLng(c.getFloat(c.getColumnIndex("latitud")),
                    c.getFloat(c.getColumnIndex("longitud")));
            final Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title(c
                    .getString(c.getColumnIndex("titulo"))).snippet(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("_id"))).position(latlong)); 

            markers.put(marker.getId(), c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("foto")));



        } while (c.moveToNext());

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(MapaLugaresActivity.this, "Añada un nuevo lugar",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

onCreate:

```
if (map != null) {
        map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new MyInfoWindowAdapter());

        addMarker();
    }
```

a greeting